# execute html and PHP code into a variable

Tags: php, view, controller

I'm trying to figure out how can I execute HTML and PHP code from a class type controller and store the result into a variable to simulate the behavior of some MVC oriented frameworks, example:

I have a variable called **$mystic_var** and I want to use this var with a strange function (I don't know which function is) to read a .php file, execute it and store the result into my $mystic_var

Assume try.php has the following content:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><?php echo "Hello world"; ?></body>
</html>
```

Then I execute $mystic_var = mystic_function('try.php'); and then if I check my $mystic_var, it will have something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Hello World</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The mystic_function is `include`.

Comment: But Include will only include the php file but isn't going to execute it and store the results

Comment: Well, including it _does_ execute it, but you will need to use output buffering to keep the results of that execution from ending up on the screen instead of in your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use output buffer

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body><?php echo "Hello world"; ?></body>
</html>
<?php $output = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Comment: Output buffering does need to be used, but I don't think OP wants to have to modify the target file.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `file_get_contents`, you will get all of the text from the file, but any PHP code within it will not be executed. If you `include` the file, the PHP will be executed, but the results of including the file will end up on your screen. You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to hold the contents of the included file instead of immediately displaying it.

```
function mystic_function($php_file) {
    ob_start();
    include $php_file;
    return ob_get_flush();
}

$mystic_var = mystic_function('try.php');

echo $mystic_var;
// or if you want to see the html
// echo htmlspecialchars($mystic_var);
```

Answer (score -1):

For example you have a php class with your function

php file..

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>@$hello_word@</body> //you should wrap strings you want to play with later into something you parse later
</html>
```

Your class

```
class myclass{

   // and you have your php function that returns the file contents..

    public function readfile($a){  //$a will store file path & name

        $contents = file_get_contents ($a);
        return $contents;

   }

}
```

Views...

```
   $myclass = new myclass();

    $mystic_var = $myclass->readfile("file.html"); // file contents saved in variable
    $replacewords = array(@$hello_word@,@some_other_stuff@);
    $replacewith = array("Hello Word","Some other stuff");

    $mystic_var = str_replace($replacewords, $replacewith ); Don't echo inside file - parse it later.
```

Note:

PHP function to read file = file_get_contents ();

Declare class => $myclass = new myclass();

Access function inside class => $myclass->readfile("file.html");

Parse variables with str_replace or other methods

Comment: `file_get_contents` will read the file, not execute the PHP. So the returned contents will have `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` instead of just `Hello World`.

Comment: You right - the file should have php variables wrapped in something like
@$hello_world@
and then parsed later
I will amend my answer